# Querying for multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am currently writing code that is supposed to query for several different records with multiple IDs. I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ID = ( 1, 2 )

SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ID = 1, 2

SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ID = '1, 2'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would work just as well. What you're looking for information on is the "IN" operator of most SQL languages ([MySQL example here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)).

what you're doing is providing a series of values as a set (right side of the IN operator) and then asking the database to bring back records whose column you're querying about (the left side of the IN operator) that have one of the values in the set.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ID = 1 or ID = 2;
```

or use short hand notation

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ID IN (1,2);
```

Answer (score 2):

use `IN` if you are comparing to multiple values.

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ID IN (1, 2)
```

which is the same for

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ID = 1 OR ID = 2
```

---

for this statement: *"... query for several different records with multiple IDs"*, I think you want to search for a group which has multiple ID, if that's the case, the problem is called `Relational Division`.

```
SELECT groupColumn
FROM   Items 
WHERE  ID IN (1, 2)
GROUP  BY groupColumn
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to type is

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ID IN (1,2)
```

**Note** for string values inside the IN brackets use single quotes ('1','2')

Answer (score 2):

Use `IN` like following

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ID IN (1, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

SYNTAX:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN (id1, id2, ..., idn)
```

Here in your case:

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ID IN (1, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
select * from items where id in (1,2);
```